# Regular Expression Validator for number with a length of 5 or 6 only

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a textbox for my `FacultyID` that should only accept a 5 or 6 digit number.

I want to use a `Regular Expression Validator` to validate the user input. What validation expression should I put in? Please help.

I'm using `ASP.NET` and `C#`

Comment: Hi, please show us the code, otherwise it is not really possible to help you...

Answer (score 3):

Use this validation expression on the validator:

```
ValidationExpression="\d{5,6}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex pattern:

```
 ^[0-9]{5,6}$
```